# Navigate back after saving in Swift UI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a simple detail view where users can input data. After pressing the save button, I would like the app to navigate back to the previous list view. The detail view is opened through a NavigationLink. I assume the action for the button needs to be adjusted in some way. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to do this you need to grab an `Environment` variable in your detail view:

```
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
```

and then call it's dismiss method in your button's action like this:

```
self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
```

A more detailed example:

```
struct DetailView: View {

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    @State var someData = ""

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Placeholder", text: $someData)
        Button(action: {
            saveData()
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() 
        }) {
            Text("Save data and go back")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a great answer! It solved my problem and it works like a charm!